# C# listview1 throws error after first selection

Tags: c#, winforms, listview

On my windows forms I have a listview control and I have an event handler of

```
private void listView1_SelectedIndexChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
```

the problme is after the first selection I am getting an error that says:

```
System.ArgumentOutOfRangeException: 'InvalidArgument=Value of '0' is not vaild for 'index'. Parameter name:index'
```

This is the full code:

```
private void listView1_SelectedIndexChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
      MessageBox.Show(listView1.SelectedItems[0].Text);
}
```

This code allows for one selection to show up in a message box but the next selection comes up with the above error. Any ideas of how to fix this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your datasource or list's length is important in this case, without knowing that, you can check length inside event. The error says that; **SelecteItems** doesn't have any item inside. When you try to select 0 index of the list, it throws that the list doesn't have any item at index 0.

```
private void listView1_SelectedIndexChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
{   
     if(listView1.SelectedItems.Count > 0){
        MessageBox.Show(listView1.SelectedItems[0].Text);
     }
}
```

Hope helps,

Answer (score 0):

Check selected items count before to retrieve the selected item.

```
private void listView1_SelectedIndexChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
      if(listView1.SelectedItems.Count > 0)
         MessageBox.Show(listView1.SelectedItems[0].Text);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Yes that is the answer thank you!

```
private void listView1_SelectedIndexChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
      if(listView1.SelectedItems.Count > 0)
         MessageBox.Show(listView1.SelectedItems[0].Text);
}
```